# Vim Undo command (the one with the with capital U)

Tags: vim, vi

I don't understand how the undo line command works.

The documentation says `Undo all latest changes on one line.`

What is the definition of `all latest changes` here?

One behaviour I have noticed is that sometimes U undoes all writes after the very first write on a line. But this is not consistent. For example, when I open a new file and edit the first line, writing multiple times, the `U` command undoes every single change.

I haven't been able to find anything concrete from my google searches either.

Comment: You may want to check out an undo history plugin like [Gundo](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/gundo.vim/). There is also what looks like an experimental plugin that does undo on visually selected lines called [selective-undo.vim](https://github.com/jaxbot/selective-undo.vim)

Comment: yeah.. i found this to very confusing as well. what throws me off sometimes, is when I have accidentally turn on caps lock, and it does some very weird undos..

Answer (score 20):

In my understanding *all latest changes* means going back the change history until a change in a *different* line is encountered, and stop there. So if you start with an empty buffer and edit only one line (repeatedly), all additions will be wiped by `U`.

Vim generally merges near changes occurring in the same line; these appear as a single entry in `:changes`.

Comment: thank you for mentioning the :changes command. I didn't know about that. That gives me an opening window, although I'm seeing --invalid--'s at the moment.

Comment: Also note that uppercase `U` "undoes" the changes as a _fresh edit_, not by reverting to a previous state like lowercase `u`. So if you don't like what `U` did, you can just hit `u` to undo it (and `C-r` to redo it -- like any other edit).

Answer (score 3):

U: return the last line which was modified to its original state (reverse all changes in last modified line)

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Undo_and_Redo